# Compound Option Monte Carlo Methods Reference Request

Tags: option-pricing, monte-carlo, reference-request

I am interested in valuing option where the underlying security is similar (not exact) to an option. The underlying security might be a Preferred Share (option to convert into common share plus dividend). I am going over the paper Valuation of Compound options by Geske, however I want to inquire if anyone has some references for valuing such securities using Monte Carlo method.

The main reason I ask is because the underlying security (option) of the compound option for my case tend to have several conditions that requires me to model them using Monte Carlo Methods.

I am currently trying to figure out if I can apply the Longstaff Schwarz regression method to value such instruments. Any advice or references/papers would be very helpful. I am not interested in using call-put parity formulas to value such instruments, as they do not apply to my case. Thanks for the help.